# On Sql Azure, duplicate database appears in square brackets

Tags: entity-framework, azure, azure-sql-database

I have a SQL Azure database called Palladium.

I just logged into the Windows Azure portal, and Palladium is showing up twice now, and the duplicate is named [Palladium] with square brackets.

Any idea what this is?

I am using Code First and I've been fumbling around with different connection strings (serious problems today...), and they all actually do specify [Palladium] for some reason. When I go into the new one and click to generate a connection string, it actually says [[Palladium]]]. That's right, that's three square brackets on the end.

I *am* using Entity Framework with Code First, but as far as I know the part that actually drops and modifies the database is disabled.

**Solution:** I still have no idea what that database was. It appears to be empty, and the portal seemed confused by it (not letting me delete it, select certain things, etc). However, through SSMS I was able to drop it no problem and now everything seems fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can tell you why the db gets created - it's created by the ASP.Net universal providers.

If you had checked the tables in your [Palladium] database you would have noticed only the membership tables that are used by the ASP.Net universal providers. (Applications, Memberships, Profiles, Roles, Users and UsersInRoles)

One of the features of these providers is that they can automatically create the membership tables for you in your database. This is what happened to you - the web.config had the square brackets around it as indicated by Gary's answer. So the automatic creation of the membership tables took that connection string too literally and created a DB with the square brackets.

I'm interested to know whether you left the square brackets in your web.config and just deleted the DB. If it started working under those conditions, then that indicates to me that this must be an Azure bug.

Comment: I think the root of my problem was that there are some counter-intuitive (even ugly) things about linked resources. 

When I linked my SQL Database to my Web Site, I didn't realize that the connection string under WebSite > Configure > Connection Strings is intended to override whatever is in your web.config, *and it is different than what you get when you look at the ADO.NET connection string the DB!*. This led to all sorts of attempts and tweaks and fails. I have no idea which combination of connection string parts resulted in [Palladium] being created.  <cntd>

Comment: I just checked and the one in WebSites > Configuration (the only one that matters) does not have brackets. In my case, the connection string it created was called Palladium, and I had to renamed it to PalladiumContext since that's what mine is called. I don't know if it's okay to delete the generated connection and put this connection string in my web.config transform, or if there's something special abut these 'connection strings for linked resources'. A little experimentation will tell. But this little quirk took me hours to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

Brian, even though you appear to have solved your particular issue, I want to add a message here since this is one of the first Google search results for people having the [] square bracket problem in their database name.

I have previously encountered this issue where the database name appears to have square brackets [] on azure. In my case it was not code first. Let's say I create a new database using the Azure portal, and name it Palladium. In order to get the connection string for it, I go to the dashboard page of the sql database and click the 'show connection strings' link that appears on the right. This connection string needs to be placed in your web.config file replacing the contents of the connectionstring="".
Before doing that, notice that for some reason the connection string contains the string "Database=[Palladium]". I believe you have already noticed this. This is a problem.. I do not know why Azure insists on putting [] around the database name, but you must remove those square brackets from around the word Palladium before using it as your connection string.  (Also don't forget to replace the string "{your_password_here}" with the actual password).

That fixed my problem, and I have been doing this routinely for some months now without problems. Still don't know why Azure puts [] in the first place.

I am thinking this solution would apply even to someone using codefirst since you would still need to create the database on Azure and get the connection string, since code first creates the tables, not the db itself.